# Curved Carrousel

Tags: menu, rotation, carousel, slideshow

Is there any well-known method to create a carousel along a curved path, with jQuery or CSS?

Scene 1 enter image description here So, there is Scene 2 enter image description here I have all icons used in SVG format. I think I can use three bootstrap containers overlayed. The bottom layer will show the informations above; the middle layer the half wheel and controlers buttons; and the top layer the inferior submenu!... It`s only an idea.
Can somebody help me???
Thanks

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

I need a solution using Bootstrap, Jquery and CSS. Could anyone help?